# Residue lapping compound in valve shafts

Tags: valve

I have read that valve lapping compound, as it is abrasive, should by no means get into valve guides as it will impede the reciprocal motion or damage the valve. Should I worry about small amount residue amounts that are left over in the valve shaft and can be seen through intake runners but difficult to reach?  Should I try to clean it with an air pistol or water blast?

Answer (score 3):

If you are hand lapping the valves you should have the springs, retainers, etc removed. You can remove the valve and clean the valve stems and guides. I would use a  parts cleaning solvent on the valves. Use a nylon or plastic brush on the guides. A steel brush may scratch the inside of the guides.

Comment: of course, they were all off when i was lapping

Comment: are you saying remove the valve after lapping to clean it out and then put it back in for final reassembly ?

Comment: Yes , you want the valves and guides clean and lightly oiled. Beside the abrasive residue getting into the vale guide you could also draw it into the  combustion chamber and deposit it on the rings or cylinder wall.

Comment: OK.  i didn't do it that way exactly.  i oiled the stem before lapping, put it in, lap and then put the spring back in and load it.

Comment: but i guess it's too late now unless i wanted to disassemble for cleaning, which i don't.  i will just reach in with a pick and some tissue rapped around.  harder that way but easier than removing the valves all over

Comment: Now it is even more important to clean everything.  The residual grit will stick to the oil and lapp the valve guide.

Comment: but it will not do so if i clean it real good, right ?

Comment: It is hard to say for sure. But if you left compound on the valve face it will migrate into the combustion chamber. How much you left and how much damage it could do is  anybodys'  quess.

Comment: @amphibient - Follow mikes advice: ***disassemble and clean everything***. You will be sorry if you don't as you will destroy the heads (well, at least the valves, seats, and guides). Take the time and do it right. Reaching in with something to clean areas will not get things as clean as they need to be. Remember what I said: ***Cleanliness is next to Godliness.*** If you do it right, you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: i am definitely not disassembling.  i will clean with air or water blasts coning through the intake runners

Comment: are you saying that, once i have lapped a valve to get a satisfactory tune out when lapping it, i should take it out and clean all the compound before putting it back in ?

Comment: yes and make sure it goes into the same position in the cylinder head it came from after lapping.